# Resize an icon in react native paper BottomNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am new to react-native-paper and am trying to learn how to use the BottomNavigation. I am looking at the example from react-native-paper [documentation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html) but am unable to identify how to increase one of the icons size.

Suppose I have 5 icons, [Album, Library, New, Favorite, Purchased] and want to increate the size of the middle icon, New, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to provide a custom component for the icon for the tab you need. According the doc it uses material community icons. So you can simply do this.

Import materialcommmunityicons

```
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
```

When creating the navigator you can provide an icon like below

```
   { key: 'music', title: 'Music', icon:(props)=> <MaterialCommunityIcons {...props} name='queue-music' size={30}/> },
```

you have to pass the props to make sure that the color and other props are passed.
You can see the full list of icons in the [directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)